# does onion sites uses any standard for blocking crawler

Tags: configuration, onion-services, onion-routing, blocked-services

does onion sites uses robot.txt files to hide or restrict crawlers? as i know normal webservices uses robot.txt files to stop google crwaler from knowing more about the website or limitaions. so does the onion site uses such files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, onion sites are just the same web sites with all the standards and conventions